Flask API Deployment on Azure Fails to Start Due to Container Timeout (2GB Model Size)
I'm deploying a Flask API on Azure App Service (Premium V3 P2V3 plan) with models of size ~2 GB through local git. However, I am encountering the following error in the logs during startup:
2024-12-10T12:06:33.635Z ERROR - Container tdoc3_0_bded436f for site tdoc3 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.5782541 sec
2024-12-10T12:06:33.651Z ERROR - Container tdoc3_0_bded436f didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-12-10T12:06:33.658Z INFO  - Stopping site tdoc3 because it failed during startup.

apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmagic1 \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmupdf-dev \
    mupdf-tools \
    tesseract-ocr \
    poppler-utils \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libopencv-dev && \
    gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 700 --log-level debug app:app

Details:
Plan: Premium V3 P2V3
Model Size: ~2 GB
Flask API setup using gunicorn
Running on port 8000
I am getting a container timeout error, and the app does not respond to HTTP pings.
What I’ve Tried:
Increased the timeout value (--timeout 700) in the gunicorn command.
Ensured that all required dependencies are installed in the container.
Questions:
Is there a known limitation on Azure App Service regarding container startup times for large models or dependencies?
Could the 2GB model size be causing the timeout? If so, how can I optimize my app or model loading to avoid this issue?
Are there any configurations I need to change in my Azure App Service (e.g., increasing the startup timeout, adjusting memory settings) to accommodate larger model sizes?
Additional Info:
Azure Premium V3 P2V3 plan (more than sufficient resources).
Logs indicate that the container fails to respond within the expected time.
Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

how are you deploying your app

Please share you code that you've tried.

If your deploying via container registry, please share your dockerfile

Through local git not through container registry

https://github.com/JEEVA-JOSLIN/flask-13-new I couldn't upload the models which are of bigger size in github so I used local git for that

Joshlin please increase the worker timeout like gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout 1800 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level debug app:app

Also add this environment variable in your azure web app WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 1800

I have increased the time limit but still didn't work

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


2024-12-10T12:06:33.635Z ERROR - Container tdoc3_0_bded436f for site tdoc3 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.5782541 sec

The error you're encountering is due to the lengthy dependency installations and the large model size causing the startup to exceed the allowed timeout.

To resolve the issue, move the dependency installations out of the startup.sh script.
You can pre-install them in the App Service runtime using an App Service Build Script.
Run the below commands to install the dependencies in Azure app service Kudu console.

apt-get update
apt-get install -y libmagic1 build-essential python3-dev libjpeg-dev libmupdf-dev mupdf-tools tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev poppler-utils libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-0 libopencv-dev libatlas-base-dev libopenjp2-7 libtiff5

Go to kudu console of your Azure web app -> SSH and run the commands as shown.

Now as the dependencies are installed, you can remove the dependencies and modify the startup.sh script to focus only on running the app.
Final Startup .sh:
gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 1800 --log-level debug app:app

As your model size is 2 GB that may cause delays, so you can upload your model to Azure blob storage.
Please refer this doc for better understanding about managing files in Azure blob storage.
If the issue persists, try using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) or Azure Container Instances (ACI) for better resource control and to avoid startup time restrictions.

@Jeeva Joslin is your issue resolved?
